# Django объединение запросов сессии и пользователя

Tags: django

Очень не нравится что в Django выполняется каждый раз лишний зарпос к базе при обращении к странице, а именно получение сессии и потом получение пользователя. Можно ли как то объединить их?

Вот что постоянно выполняется

```
SELECT * FROM "django_session" WHERE "django_session"."session_key" = '18xvt5035kkw66m2yckbmvjttxqd5ri4'
SELECT * FROM "accounts_user" WHERE "accounts_user"."id" = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT * FROM "django_session" WHERE "django_session"."session_key" = '18xvt5035kkw66m2yckbmvjttxqd5ri4'

Можете использовать [django-redis-sessions](https://github.com/martinrusev/django-redis-sessions), сессии будут храниться в Redis

Comment: У меня на других проектах в memcached они хранятся, но тут все в базе, и вопрос всетаки в том можно ли объединить запрос

Comment: "accounts_user" – это ваша таблица?

Comment: Модель моя, но вызов делает Django, подключена как AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User' тоесть я сам никаких запросов не делаю

Comment: > Очень не нравится что в Django выполняется каждый раз лишний зарпос к базе при обращении к странице

может Вы где-то обращаетесь к `request.user` ?

Comment: Естественно! Просто при обращении к сессии, хотелось бы сделать чтобы получались данные сразу и объекта юзера. После чего они бы кэшировались, и в следущий раз при обращении в коде к объекту юзера брать данные уже из кэша

Comment: может Вам самому сохранять в сессии нужный данные и после брать их оттуда?

Comment: Вопрос не в этом. Поставлен конкретный вопрос, можно ли стандартно както объединить, не нужно что то другое предлагать. Как сделать по другому куча решений, нужно решить текущую проблему.